# Using Makefile for editing files rather than creating them

Tags: makefile

I was thinking about using Make for small checks for my dev setup. One thing I want is to check that a particular string exists in a file before doing some action. If I wanted to create the entire file it would be trivial

```
action: filename
    ...

filename:
    echo 'blah' >> filename
```

But how can this logic be applied to actions, like `grep`? My dependency isn't that a file exists, it's that the file has correct content.

I'm asking specifically about Make and not other solutions like chef/puppet

Answer (score 0):

You can run any shell commands you want in a make recipe. As many of them as you want also.

So if you need to run `grep` before doing something else just do that.

Just remember that every line in a recipe is run in its own shell session so they don't share state.

So this:

```
action: filename
    ...

filename:
    grep -qw blah $@ || echo 'blah' > $@
```

runs `grep` on `filename` (via the [automatic variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) for the current target `$@`) looking for whole words and quitting on the first match (`-q`).

If `grep` finds `blah` then it will return success and the `||` will short-circuit and the recipe is done. If `grep` fails then the `||` will trigger and the `echo` will run.

You might be tempted to do things that require the inverse logic do X only if Y is true:

```
filename:
    grep -qw blah $@ && echo blah2 > $@
```

but that doesn't work correctly. When `grep` fails the `&&` short-circuits and `make` sees a recipe failure and bails the `make` process out with an error.

You need this instead.

```
filename:
    ! grep -qw blah $@ || echo blah2 > $@
```

to invert the logic and ensure that the "failure" from grep is seen as success as far as make is concerned.

That all being said in this specific example if `filename` exists at all then that recipe won't ever run as it has no prerequisites so `make` will *always* consider it up to date. To work around that you need to give the file a prerequisite that will force it to be considered out of date. Specifically a [force target](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Force-Targets).

Don't follow the advice about `.PHONY` for this case though. `.PHONY` targets should never be prerequisites of non-`.PHONY` targets.

Comment: Yeah, so how can a prerequisite be a function rather than another file?

Comment: It can't. make only deals with files. You can use a [stamp file](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Empty-Targets) to record outside events though. And note that if a target runs but doesn't update the file's modification time then make won't consider that file as updated and things that depend on it won't need to be run.

Comment: using a force target / .phony doesn't leverage make correctly. It will always execute something and never have a `make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.` which breaks the utility of `make -q`

Comment: It leverages make correctly it just prevents `-q` from working which is, I'll admit, unfortunate but a loss I've long since given up on personally since working around that is nigh-on impossible in complicated cases in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a test in the target's recipe (As Etan posted before I could complete this answer...).   If you do want to do this using just make logic, you could do something along the lines of:

```
actions: $(if $(shell grep -q $$string filename && echo y),filename,)

filename:
    echo blah >> $@
```

If filename contains the string, then there will be an `actions: filename` dependency, and filename will be built when you build actions.   Notice, though that this will check whether the string exists in filename at the time the makefile is parsed -- if filename is generated, or modified in this makefile, then it would not effect whether the action is run.   If you want to test right before overwriting the file, then you would use a bash if statement in the recipe itself.

Comment: I cna't get it to work if `filename` file already exists.  Should the filename be a phony target? I think wit the right tweaking this can work, but I'm also having problems getting that `if` statement to fail... it always returns true :(

Comment: Sorry, my bad -- you have to use `$(shell command)` instead of `\`command\`` in this case due to the order that makefile expands.  I've edited my response to reflect this.

Comment: Also, you can add a test if the file exists before that so you don't get output on stderr if the file does not exist:   `$(if $(shell [ -e filename ] && grep -q XXX filename && echo y)`

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on what @john wrote I got the following to work:

```
TEST_FILE=filename
.PHONY: ${TEST_FILE}
string=testing

filecheck=$(shell grep -qw ${string} ${TEST_FILE} || echo ${TEST_FILE})

all: ${filecheck}

${TEST_FILE}:
    echo 'changing the file'
    echo ${string} >> ${TEST_FILE}
```

Here the file on which I'm operating is a `.PHONY` target. I think that's ok because I'm actually not creating the file, just modifying it. This *will* work if the file does not exist, or exists without the needed string.

Comment: This runs the `grep` shell every time the makefile is parsed (and potentially multiple times each time the makefile is parsed unless you use `filecheck:=$(shell ...)`) but other than that seems to cover the goal.